Why is r giving me a code error of model.frame.default
I'm trying to write a code.

Regress y on x, x2, and their interaction. Based on the regression-estimated coefficients, what is the effect on y of shifting x from -0.5 to -0.7 with x2 held at 1?

fit <- lm(y ~ x + x2 + x:x2)
predict(fit, data.frame(x=-0.7, x2=1)) - predict(fit, data.frame(x=-0.5, x2=1))

But this message is showing up,
> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x + x.bar + x:x.bar, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x.bar') 

I'm not sure where I am going wrong or if more info is needed for someone to help me.

I tried, but I can't reproduce your example. Can we have a [mcve] please? In general, you should use the data= argument whenever you use model-fitting functions like lm; doing so may make your problem disappear. (Also, your error message is inconsistent with the code you showed: you have x2 in your code but x.bar in your error message ...)

This happens if e.g. x2 has different lengths than the other variables.
> n <- 10
> y <- rnorm(n)
> x <- rnorm(n)
> x2 <- rnorm(n - 1)^2
> 
> fit <- lm(y ~ x + x2 + x:x2)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x + x2 + x:x2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x2')

BTW, instead of y ~ x + x2 + x:x2 you can simply do y ~ x*x2. Or even y ~ x*I(x^2) if you manually calculated x2 from x^2.
> x <- rnorm(10); y <- x + rnorm(10); x2 <- x^2
> lm(y ~ x + x2 + x:x2)$coe
(Intercept)           x          x2        x:x2 
 -0.3881758   1.5181841   0.3972592  -0.2542156 
> lm(y ~ x*x2)$coe
(Intercept)           x          x2        x:x2 
 -0.3881758   1.5181841   0.3972592  -0.2542156 
> lm(y ~ x*I(x^2))$coe
(Intercept)           x      I(x^2)    x:I(x^2) 
 -0.3881758   1.5181841   0.3972592  -0.2542156 

